# passing value from Service to many Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, service, connection

I need to pass value from service to many activities, some of them even haven't been initialized, but I want these get value in initialization. I know broadcast can be an useful way, but it's relatively slow. Is there any way can achieve this goal? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [greenrobot's EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus), using its [sticky events](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/configuration/sticky-events/) feature. Have your activities register with the bus in `onStart()` and unregister in `onStop()`. Have your service post events on the bus as needed with `postSticky()`. Your activities will then get the events:

- when they are posted
- when they register on the bus, if a sticky event was posted before they were created — they get the last such event

Comment: Will it take long between service post values and activity get values?

Comment: @LunarS: In general, no. However, typically, you want your activity to receive the event on the main application thread, so it can update its UI. If you are tying up the main application thread, that will introduce a delay before you get the event. This is not a problem with EventBus, but rather a problem with your app.

Comment: Sounds pretty good, it's much faster than broadcast receiver right?

Comment: @LunarS: It would be faster than system broadcasts. `LocalBroadcastManager` is another event bus, that happens to use `BroadcastReceiver`. It does not offer the sticky events feature. However, in terms of speed, it should be comparable to greenrobot's EventBus.

Comment: Thank you very much for your specific explanation, I will try EventBus.^^

Comment: Sorry, there's one more problem, can we subscribe or post multiple events? All in Asyntask thread right?

Comment: @LunarS: "can we subscribe or post multiple events?" -- yes. "All in Asyntask thread right?" -- you can post from whatever thread you want.

Comment: Hi, I have another quick question, will event posted already disappears if I destroy sender? Thank you!